# How can you shrink an XFS filesystem?

Tags: filesystems, xfs

I have an xfs filesystem that has some free space. Can I shrink it? I know of `xfs_growfs`. And there is `resize2fs` and `resize_reiserfs`.

Side question: is xfs not a good filesystem choice for bulk longterm file storage?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can make a backup, and then create a new smaller file system and restore.

XFS cannot be shrunk ([ref](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q:_Is_there_a_way_to_make_a_XFS_filesystem_larger_or_smaller.3F)).

Comment: +1 - there were some patches adding support for shrinking a filesystem, but they seem to have stalled now

Comment: For RedHat (and CentOS) users, see RedHat's [article 540013](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/540013).

Comment: Some documentation about XFS backup/dump/restore [XFS Dump and Restore](http://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_User_Guide/tmp/en-US/html/xfs-dump-and-restore.html), and [Red Hat 6 documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsbackuprestore.html)

Comment: @FranklinPiat, that Red Hat article requires a subscription for access.